# Shiny namespace issue with toggle and tabsetPanel

Tags: r, shiny, namespaces, toggle, shinyjs

I’m looking for some help with a simple Shiny app with a modularised design please. I think the problem is a name space issue so the example below is set out as a simplified version of my actual project.

The aim is for ‘`tab_3`’ on the `tabsetPanel` to only show when the ‘`View Tab_3`’ is checked, which works fine. I would like to update the `tabsetPanel` however to also select ‘`tab_3`’ when ‘`View Tab_3`’ is checked and this is not firing as desired.

I can get the `tabsetPanel` to also select ‘`tab_3`’ when ‘`View Tab_3`’ is checked if I wrap the tabsetPanel’s id in a namespace function, `id = ns("tab_a_tha")`, however then I lose the show/hide functionality of ‘`tab_3`’.

My hunch is that the solution lies within providing a namespace to the toggle function but I haven’t found any clues on how to approach it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

inner_moduleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(checkboxInput(ns("chckbx"), "View Tab_3", value = F)),
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tab_a_tha",
      # id = ns("tab_a_tha"),
      tabPanel('tab_1'),
      tabPanel('tab_2'),
      tabPanel('tab_3')
    )
  )
}



inner_module <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$chckbx, {
    
    toggle(condition = input$chckbx, selector = "#tab_a_tha li a[data-value=tab_3]")
    
    if(input$chckbx == T){
      updateTabsetPanel(session, 'tab_a_tha', selected = 'tab_3')
    }

  })
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput('main_ui')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$main_ui <- renderUI({inner_moduleUI('inner_ns')  })
  callModule(inner_module, 'inner_ns')
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps changing `putput` to `output` in inner_module definition could resolve your issue.

Comment: Good catch on the typo thanks (amended now)... however that didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are right the problem is with the namespace. The trick is that you can access the namespace function also in the server part of a module with `session$ns`.

Using this and wrapping the tap id in the `ns` function. We can use `paste0` to generate the new selector of the `toggle` function. We get something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

inner_moduleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(checkboxInput(ns("chckbx"), "View Tab_3", value = F)),
    tabsetPanel(
      id = ns("tab_a_tha"),
      # id = ns("tab_a_tha"),
      tabPanel('tab_1'),
      tabPanel('tab_2'),
      tabPanel('tab_3')
    )
  )
}



inner_module <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$chckbx, {
    toggle(condition = input$chckbx, selector = paste0("#",session$ns("tab_a_tha")," li a[data-value=tab_3]"))
    
    if(input$chckbx == T){
      updateTabsetPanel(session, 'tab_a_tha', selected = 'tab_3')
    }
    
  })
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput('main_ui')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$main_ui <- renderUI({inner_moduleUI('inner_ns')  })
  callModule(inner_module, 'inner_ns')
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for - many thanks @Bertil.